# On the implication of two clocks colliding with respect to time dilation

Tags: special-relativity, time-dilation

Have you ever noticed, with Special Relativity textbooks, how frequently two observers with clocks in moving vehicles are passing by each other. But what if there was an accident? Perhaps the consequence of a miscalculated trajectory or some other unforeseen anomaly. Consider then, if you will, the implication of such a mishap in the following thought experiment, conducted without observers in vehicles so that no one gets hurt.

Clock Red is travelling at half the speed of light along an X axis calibrated in light seconds. Its elapsed time is shown with respect to time dilation.

Fig 1 is taken the moment Red meets the first calibration marker and thenceforth at one second intervals. Clock Orange is stationary at the second marker.

Now here's the rub, as proposed: Clock Red is set on a collision course with Clock Orange.

[image]

The question being: If Red and Orange's timing mechanisms froze at the point of impact, what elapsed times would they show?

A prima facie case of 1.73 and 2 seconds, respectively, seems at odds when considering an action replay from Red's frame of reference.

[image]
Hmmm......

Answer (score 3):

If you draw a spacetime diagram of the first 'movie' clip in which the orange clock is at rest, you'll immediately see that the second clip is incorrect.

First, note that in the orange clock reference frame, the two *spatially separated* events, (a) orange clock reads 0 sec and (b) red clock reads 0 sec, are *simultaneous*

Due to the relativity of simultaneity, these two events are *not* simultaneous in the red clock reference frame.

But in the second clip, you show that these two events *are* simultaneous in the red clock reference frame and thus arrive at a contradiction.

---

More specifically, according to the first clip, when the orange clock reads $t = 0$, the red clock is 1 light-second away (according to rulers at rest in the orange clock reference frame).

That is to say, the coordinates of the red clock at the beginning of the first clip are $t=0, x=-1$ and the coordinates of the orange clock are, of course, $t=0, x=0$

Now, look at the situation in the red clock reference frame when the red clock reads $t' = 0$.  According to your second clip, the orange clock reads $t=0$ and is 1 light-second away (according to rulers at rest in the red clock reference frame).$\quad$*But this isn't true*.

Indeed, using a spacetime diagram, it's easy to see that when the red clock reads $t' = 0$, the orange clock is located at $x' = 0.866$ and reads $t = 0.5$.

---

Let's see if this checks out.  Since the orange clock is moving towards the red clock with speed $c/2$ and is $0.866$ light-seconds distant when $t' = 0$, the red clock should read $t'=1.73$ when the clocks collide.$\quad$*Check*

Due to time dilation, the orange clock will advance by only 1.5 seconds before the collision and so will read $t = 0.5 + 1.5 = 2$.$\quad$*Check*